# How to instruct gcc to warn me about invalid function pointer conversion just as g++ would do?

Tags: c, gcc, function-pointers, gcc-warning

How can i instruct gcc to warn me about invalid function pointer conversions like g++ would do for the following piece of code?

And.. why doesn't gcc warn me about that? What could / will happen when passing a pointer to a to do_something()?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*void_func_t) ();
typedef void (*void_int_func_t) (int, int, int);

void do_something(void_func_t f)
{
    void_int_func_t foo = f;
    foo(1,2,3);
}

void a()
{
    printf("a\n");
}

void b(int one, int two, int three)
{
    printf("%i, %i, %i\n", one, two, three);
}

int main()
{
    do_something(a);
    do_something(b);
    return 0;   
}
```

output:

```
➜  gcc -W -Wall -Werror func.c 
➜  ./a.out
a
1, 2, 3
```

c++, however would warn / give errors

```
g++ -W -Wall -Werror func.c
func.c: In function ‘void do_something(void_func_t)’:
func.c:8:27: error: invalid conversion from ‘void_func_t {aka void (*)()}’ to ‘void_int_func_t {aka void (*)(int, int, int)}’ [-fpermissive]
func.c: In function ‘int main()’:
func.c:25:19: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(int, int, int)’ to ‘void_func_t {aka void (*)()}’ [-fpermissive]
func.c:6:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void do_something(void_func_t)’ [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: Can you use `clang` instead of `gcc` where `-Weverything` is available?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. If you use an obsoletcence, yet valid C feature, why should a compliant compiler warn?

Comment: no, @FiddlingBits thats not possible in my case. 
@Olaf, it wasn't clear to me that there´s such a substantial difference between delcaring a function as `void foo()` or `void foo(void)` in C. That´s why i was wondering and why i asked this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function prototype with empty parenthesis is an obsolescent<sup>1</sup> feature. Don't use it.

If you use the correct declaration, you will get warnings:

```
typedef void(*void_func_t)(void);
```

Due to this old feature, the types `void(*)()` and `void(*)(int, int, int)` are compatible. The former type takes an unspecified number of arguments. This is doubly problematic, because there is no warning from the compiler, and if you call the function with incorrect number of arguments, the behavior is undefined.

Unlike in C, in C++ empty parenthesis mean that the function takes no arguments, thus `void(*)()` is equivalent to `void(*)(void)`.

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.11.6 Function declarators
1)
The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter
type declarators) is an obsolescent feature.

Comment: thanks for the reference, it helps, of course, to know what to look for... seems like -Wstrict-prototypes would help to spot those smells but i fear that would lead to 1000 warnings in my code base ...